# Not getting grep result using popen with cat and multiple process pipes

Tags: python-3.x, grep, subprocess, popen, cat

I am trying to get grep to work using pipes and subprocess. I've double-checked the cat and I know it's working, but for some reason the grep isn't returning anything, even though when I run it through the terminal, it works just fine. I'm wondering if I have the command constructed correctly, as it doesn't give the desired output, and I can't figure out why.

I'm trying to retrieve a few specific lines of data from a file I've already retrieved from a server. I've been having a lot of issues with getting grep to work and perhaps I do not simply understand how it works.

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["cat", "result.txt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "tshaper"], stdin=p1.stdout, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
o = p1.communicate()
print(o)
p1.stdout.close()
out, err = p2.communicate()
print(out)
```

The output for the file I have when I run this command (cat result.txt | grep "tshaper") on the terminal:

```
tshaper.1.devname=eth0 
tshaper.1.input.burst=0
tshaper.1.input.rate=25000
tshaper.1.input.status=enabled
tshaper.1.output.burst=0
tshaper.1.output.rate=25000
tshaper.1.output.status=enabled
tshaper.1.status=enabled
tshaper.status=disabled
```

My results running the command in the script:

```
(b'', b'')
```

where the tuple is the stdout, stderr respectively of the p2 process.

**EDIT:**

I changed the command based on the Popen documentation to

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['result.txt', 'cat'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                  stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=os.getcwd())
```

to the p1 subprocess statement. While I was able to get the output in stderr, it didn't really change anything, saying

```
(b'', b'cat: 1: cat: result.txt: not found\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

**FYI:** You got this error: `(b'', b'cat: 1: cat: result.txt: not found\n')` because you have changed the seq. of commands in your `Popen` method:  `['result.txt', 'cat']` (Based on your question).

I have written a working solution which provides the expected output.

`Python3.6.6` has been used for it.

**result.txt file:**

I have changed some lines to test the `grep` command.

```
tshaper.1.devname=eth0
ashaper.1.input.burst=0
bshaper.1.input.rate=25000
tshaper.1.input.status=enabled
tshaper.1.output.burst=0
cshaper.1.output.rate=25000
tshaper.1.output.status=enabled
dshaper.1.status=enabled
tshaper.status=disabled
```

**Code:**

I have made an understandable printing but it is not necessary if you only need the output of `grep`. (It is a bytesl-like object in Python3)

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen(['cat', 'result.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.check_output(["grep", "tshaper"], stdin=p1.stdout)
print("\n".join(p2.decode("utf-8").split(" ")))
```

**Otuput:**

You can see the `grep` filters the lines from `cat` command as it is expected.

```
>>> python3 test.py 
tshaper.1.devname=eth0
tshaper.1.input.status=enabled
tshaper.1.output.burst=0
tshaper.1.output.status=enabled
tshaper.status=disabled
```